# 3D in Web Browser on Ipad

Tags: ios, web, browser, 3d

Is there any way to show 3D Model on Ipad in Web Browser? iOs doesn't support WebGL, Unity WebPlayer. Some sites like kevs3d.co.uk/dev/phoria/test0k.html works correct. Does HTML5 with phoria.js or HTML5 allow to render hight-poly model?
Also, 3d model might be dynamically created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's really simple like boxes then you can go with css3 http://beta.theexpressiveweb.com/ but it has limitations( [Sample Code for site -> the expressive web from Adobe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23672801/sample-code-for-site-the-expressive-web-from-adobe/23674419#23674419)) 
Best solution will be rendering WebGL(OpenGL) on the server side and streaming it to the device  while reading input from the client and sending it back to the server. It enables  rendering on any scale in device agnostic  way and it will be easy to transfer WebGL(OpenGL) based solution to the client side when it will be supported. Also you can use service like http://cloudmach.com/